# Jsoup inserts empty TextNodes

Tags: jsoup

As seen on the screenshot, jsoup inserts empty TextNode before/after every other child node. Is there a way to turn that off? Or do i do something wrong? Is there any kind of reason why those exist?

Jsoup 1.8.2 if it helps.

[image: Example]

Comment: Does this actually cause any problems ? I'm guessing that the text nodes are not empty, but that they contain the spaces and linebreaks between the actual elements.

Comment: Huh, i didn't think about it. The may actually contain them. As for the problems - they do cause them since childnodes().size() no longer returns correct data and i also can't just blindly loop through them since i need to check if item is an actual element or just "empty" TextNode.

Comment: Maybe you could file a bug then. Should not be too complicated to loop through them and ignore the empty ones though.

Comment: please what IDE you use

Comment: This looks like intelij

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA. But it uses default compiler and this occurs on runtime too.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is there a way to turn that off?*

No, since it's the normal behavior of Jsoup HTML parser.

> Or do i do something wrong?

The method invoked maybe the root cause of the whole issue.

> Is there any kind of reason why those exist?

Each time a text is found in an HTML document, it is presented as a `TextNode` in the final HTML object tree (`Document`).

If the HTML document's author puts a line break before an element, Jsoup will create a TextNode for this line break.

> (...) childnodes().size() no longer returns correct data

I think the heart of the problem is here. Instead of calling `Node#childnodes()`, call the [`Element#children()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#children--) method. This method will filter out the empty `TextNode`s for you.

Alternatively, you can use the following code snippet to get the data:

```
Document doc = ...
Elements tds = doc.select("table tr > td");
if (tds.size() == 0) {
   // No td found ...
}

// ...
```

**Jsoup 1.8.2**